# Tkinter base de datos y condicionales

Tags: python-3.x

en Python quiero implementar condicionales en tkinter referente a una base de datos y que cuando le doy validar en la tabla me muestre el error con la fila de un color diferente.

```
global sw
archivo = filename
with open(archivo, "r") as archivo_lectura:
    nl = 0
    sw = 0
    ventana_tabla = Toplevel(root)
    ventana_tabla.title("Tabla de Usuarios")
    tabla = ttk.Treeview(ventana_tabla)
    tabla['columns'] = ('Codigo', 'Tipo', 'Documento', 'Apellido', 'Segundo Apellido', 'Nombre1', 'Segundo nombre',
                        'Fecha Nacimiento', 'Genero', 'Sisben')
    tabla.column('#0', width=0, stretch=NO)
    tabla.column('Codigo', anchor=CENTER, width=100)
    tabla.column('Tipo', anchor=CENTER, width=100)
    tabla.column('Documento', anchor=CENTER, width=150)
    tabla.column('Apellido', anchor=CENTER, width=100)
    tabla.column('Segundo Apellido', anchor=CENTER, width=100)
    tabla.column('Nombre1', anchor=CENTER, width=100)
    tabla.column('Segundo nombre', anchor=CENTER, width=100)
    tabla.column('Fecha Nacimiento', anchor=CENTER, width=150)
    tabla.column('Genero', anchor=CENTER, width=100)
    tabla.column('Sisben', anchor=CENTER, width=150)
    #agregar colunmas
    tabla.heading('#0', text='', anchor=CENTER)
    tabla.heading('Codigo', text='Codigo', anchor=CENTER)
    tabla.heading('Tipo', text='Tipo', anchor=CENTER)
    tabla.heading('Documento', text='Documento', anchor=CENTER)
    tabla.heading('Apellido', text='Apellido', anchor=CENTER)
    tabla.heading('Segundo Apellido', text='Segundo Apellido', anchor=CENTER)
    tabla.heading('Nombre1', text='Nombre1', anchor=CENTER)
    tabla.heading('Segundo nombre', text='Segundo nombre', anchor=CENTER)
    tabla.heading('Fecha Nacimiento', text='Fecha Nacimiento', anchor=CENTER)
    tabla.heading('Genero', text='Genero', anchor=CENTER)
    tabla.heading('Sisben', text='Sisben', anchor=CENTER)        
    #ciclo que organiza
    for linea in archivo_lectura:
        nl += 1
        linea = linea.rstrip()
        registro = linea.split(sep=',')
        codigo = registro[0]
        tipo = registro[1]
        documento = registro[2]
        apellido = registro[3]
        sec_apellido = registro[4]
        nombre1 = registro[5]
        nombre2 = registro[6]
        fecha_nacimiento = registro[7]
        genero = registro[8]
        Sisben = registro[9]
        tabla.insert(parent='', index='end', iid=nl, text='', values=(
            codigo, tipo, documento, apellido, sec_apellido, nombre1, nombre2, fecha_nacimiento, genero, Sisben
        )).casefold
        if tipo in ["sx"]:
            tabla.tag_configure(background='green')

            
    tabla.pack(fill='both', expand=True)
```

En esta parte quiero agregar las condiciones y cuando le de validar me muestre lo correspondiente en la tabla de la base de datos (fila en rojo o cualquier otro color).

```
 if tipo in ["sx"]:
            tabla.tag_configure(background='green')
```

intente introducir este condicional pero no me muestra ni error ni hace lo que quiero que haga